# Limit SQL query to one on one join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with requests and responses in the table. For most records, we are able to track the response for a request based on a tracking field. However, since the requests go out to third parties, we cannot always control the incoming responses and some external parties do not provide a tracking value.

For now, I have a query which queries the records and attempts to find a response record for the same account that is within 3 days of the request, since responses can come in anywhere from 1-3 days after the request.

This query works for 99.9% of records. However, in some scenarios two requests are sent out on same day, or one day after and the response comes back 1-2 days later. In these scenarios, I have 4 records in the join because each of the 2 requests join to each of the 2 responses, to produce 4 records. Although I have not encountered the scenario, I am sure it is possible for a scenario where 3 requests will match 3 responses, to produce 9 record.

Example Data:

```
ID       | AccountNo   | TransReqDate | TransCompletedDate | TransType
3934023  | 0394212345  | 3/13/2017    | 3/13/2017          | Request
3934317  | 0394212345  | 3/14/2017    | 3/14/2017          | Request
3937450  | 0394212345  |              | 3/14/2017          | Response
3941189  | 0394212345  |              | 3/15/2017          | Response
3847921  | 0740112345  | 2/16/2017    | 2/16/2017          | Request
3848095  | 0740112345  | 2/16/2017    | 2/16/2017          | Request
3850082  | 0740112345  |              | 2/17/2017          | Response
3850084  | 0740112345  |              | 2/17/2017          | Response
```

Query:

```
select *
from MTPTransaction Request
    left join MTPTransaction  Response
        on Request.AccountNo=Response.AccountNo and
            Request.ID<Response.ID
            Response.TransCompletedDate > Request.TransCompletedDate and 
            Response.TransCompletedDate < dateadd(D,3,Request.TransCompletedDate)
where Request.TransType='Request' and Response.TransType='Response'
```

Expected Result:

```
ID       | AccountNo   | TransReqDate | TransCompletedDate | TransType
3934023  | 0394212345  | 3/13/2017    | 3/13/2017          | 3937450  | 0394212345  |             | 3/14/2017
3934317  | 0394212345  | 3/14/2017    | 3/14/2017          | 3941189  | 0394212345  |             | 3/15/2017
3847921  | 0740112345  | 2/16/2017    | 2/16/2017          | 3850082  | 0740112345  |             | 2/17/2017
3848095  | 0740112345  | 2/16/2017    | 2/16/2017          | 3850084  | 0740112345  |             | 2/17/2017
```

My goal is two match the request with the lowest PK value to the response with the lowest PK value and the request with the highest PK value to the response with the highest PK value. And similarly match 1 request to 1 response for any record in between the lowest and highest PK values.

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: First you would still need to join, to get all possible combinations - 2,4,9.... although if the case indeed is that there is no tracking field as you say, then there is nothing to join on - so not sure there. Then you can sort the result by lowest request and response id's and filter the required data in the application layer may be.

Comment: also consider posting your expected output

Comment: Are these two assumptions correct: 1) There is never more than one response per request. 2) Some requests remain without response; so either a request gets a response within three days or it doesn't get any response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about this query?

```
;WITH    RequestCTE
      AS ( SELECT   AccountNo ,
                    ID ,
                    TransReqDate ,
                    TransCompletedDate ,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY AccountNo ORDER BY id ASC ) AS RN
           FROM     MTPTransaction request
           WHERE    TransType = 'Request'
         ),
    ResponseCTE
      AS ( SELECT   AccountNo ,
                    ID ,
                    TransReqDate ,
                    TransCompletedDate ,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY AccountNo ORDER BY id ASC ) AS RN
           FROM     MTPTransaction request
           WHERE    TransType = 'Response'
         )
SELECT  *
FROM    RequestCTE req
        LEFT JOIN ResponseCTE res ON req.AccountNo = res.AccountNo
                                     AND req.RN = res.RN
                                     AND res.TransCompletedDate > req.TransCompletedDate
                                     AND res.TransCompletedDate < DATEADD(D,
                                                          3,
                                                          req.TransCompletedDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to existing answer +1

```
;WITH CTE
   AS ( SELECT  AccountNo ,
                ID ,
                TransReqDate ,
                TransCompletedDate ,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY AccountNo, TransType ORDER BY id ASC ) AS RN
          FROM  MTPTransaction 
      )
SELECT *
  FROM CTE req
  LEFT JOIN CTE res 
    ON req.AccountNo = res.AccountNo
   AND req.RN = res.RN
   AND res.TransCompletedDate > req.TransCompletedDate
   AND res.TransCompletedDate < DATEADD(D, 3, req.TransCompletedDate) 
   AND req.TransType = 'Request' and res.TransType = 'Response'
```